# How to update a UILabel at a specific time determined by the user

Tags: ios, nsdate, reminders

How do I go about this.I want to update a `UILabel` with and an String in  array of Strings at a specific time determined by the user. something like a reminder.For instance at **6:35 pm** based on the device time.
I think need to use `NSDate` but I don't even know where to start from.

Comment: you want this to happen while the app is open or in the background?

Comment: Both opened and on the background